# Limits of the function $[x] = y$, where $y$ is the bigger integer smaller or equal $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am reading a notes in Analysis and I find this limit ($a$ and $b$ are positive):

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}{\frac xa\left[\frac bx\right]}=\frac ba\qquad\lim_{x\to0^+}{\frac bx\left[\frac xa\right]}=0\\
\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac xa\left[\frac bx\right]}=\frac ba\qquad\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac bx\left[\frac xa\right]}=\infty$$

[(Image that replaced math).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSTcA.png)

However I do not understand why that is the case.

Comment: Try to use $y \leqslant [y] < y+1$ and squeeze theorem.

Comment: I still don't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** As the comment above suggests you can use the fact that for all $c\in\Bbb R$, $c\leqslant[c]\lt c+1$ hence $$\frac{b}{x}\leqslant\left[\frac{b}{x}\right]\lt \frac{b}{x}+1.$$ When we're approaching $0$ from the right we have $x\gt 0$ hence multiplying both sides by $\frac xa$ yields, $$\frac{x}{a}\frac{b}{x}\leqslant\frac{x}{a}\left[\frac{b}{x}\right]\lt \frac{x}{a}\left(\dfrac{b}{x}+1\right).$$ After simplifying use the squeeze theorem. Do the same for the other cases.

Comment: But in the second case I end with $\frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{b}{x} [\frac{x}{a}] < \infty$

Comment: @MariaGuthier So it seems you already got your answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039534/why-lim-x-to0-frac-bx-left-frac-xa-right-0-where-x-sup-n-in right :) ?