# Why $\lim_{x\to0^+}{\frac bx\left[\frac xa\right]}=0$?, where $[x] = \sup\{n \in N, n \leq x\}$

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

I ask this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038865/limits-of-the-function-x-y-where-y-is-the-bigger-integer-smaller-or-equ), and I was told that using squezze theorem I could solve it, but using this idea in this limit I end with.

$\frac{b}{a} \leq \lim_{x\to0^+}{\frac bx\left[\frac xa\right]} \leq \infty$

Why?

Comment: Been attempting to fix your title, I see you've been helping. Seems better to me now.

Comment: Yeah, first edit don't work out, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x-1\leq \left [ x \right ]\leq x$